# Elasticsearch make whole index or type not_analyzed

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

When I create an elasticsearch index I don't know what fields will be inserted with new docs. So I can't specify which fields are to be `"index": "not_analyzed"` at index creation time. Fortunately I want all fields to be `not_analyzed` so is there a way to have the entire index or type, meaning all created fields, `not_analyzed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html#default-analyzers) while creating index define analyzer `default` or `default_index` to be of type `keyword`.

Example

```
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "analyzer": {
            "default": {
               "type": "keyword"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

You can also scope the analyzer per `type` at the moment but looks like it will be deprecated in the future issue [8874](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/8874).

However currently you can set default analyzer for a  *type* in the mapping as follows :

```
put test/test_type/_mapping
{
   "test_type" : { 
         "analyzer": "keyword"
   }
}
```

Comment: Gotit. The reference points to Yaml so I assume this will go into the config and would be for all indices. We need the standard analyzer for other indices. So I assume sending the above to ES as we create an index would work if we can scope it to that index. Can I scope it to a specific index or index/type?